# Get name based on id

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble getting an attribute from a foreign table:

Church Table:

```
class ChurchModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'churches'

    church_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

Minister Table:

```
class MinisterModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ministers'

    minister_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    home_assembly_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    church = db.relationship('ChurchModel') # join
    church_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('churches.church_id'))
```

When I try to do this:

```
church_name = ChurchModel.query.filter_by(church_id=self.church_id).first().name
```

I get this error:

```
church_name = ChurchModel.query.filter_by(church_id=self.church_id).first().name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: It seems like your query return None, can you provide more details about the function that handles that route.

Comment: Im doing a pretty basic parser grab (using flask's reqparse) and using this function to take the json and create db objects `def post(self, name): data = Minister.parser.parse_args() minister = MinisterModel(name,data['home_assembly_id']) minister.save_to_db()`

Comment: Your database does not have a row(s) in the `ministers` table corresponding to the given `church_id`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
`church_name = ChurchModel.query.filter(ChurchModel.church_id==self.church_id).first().name`

Answer (score -2):

Try below

```
church_query_object = ChurchModel.query.filter_by(ChurchModel.church_id == self.church_id).first()
# Then you get name from church_query_object
church_name = church_query_object.name
```

Comment: I get a new error with that: `File "./models/minister.py", line 32, in json
    church_query_object = ChurchModel.query.filter_by(ChurchModel.church_id == self.church_id).first()
TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: Use `filter()` not `filter_by()`.